# get target user permission name according to role

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

im managing my registerd users... now i want see which user have which permission according the her/his role .. i want to show permissions in check box and make them check if user have that role. problem is target user permission according her role

my controller to view target user permission:

```
 public function view(Request $request, User $user){

        $roles = Role::with('permissions')->get();
        $permissions = Permission::get();
        return view('adminarea.roles.view', compact('roles','user', 'permissions'));
    }
```

Blade file:

```
    @foreach ( $permissions as $per )

<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">

        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="permissions_ids[]" id="permissions"
            value="{{ $per->id }}" style="margin-right:5px" @if (?)
        checked="true"
        @endif>

        <label class="custom-control-label" for="permissions">{{ $per->name }}</label>
    </div>


    @endforeach
```

**Model Relations :**

Role table:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this
        ->belongsToMany('App\User')
        ->withTimestamps();
}



public function permissions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class, 'roles_permissions');
}
```

Permission table:

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'roles_permissions');
}
```

User table:

```
   public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'users_roles');
    }
```

**Table Structure** :

this is my roles_permission schema:

```
Schema::create('roles_permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('permission_id');

        //FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINTS
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('permission_id')->references('id')->on('permissions')->onDelete('cascade');

        //SETTING THE PRIMARY KEYS
        $table->primary(['role_id', 'permission_id']);
    });
```

and users_role schema :

```
 Schema::create('users_roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');

        //FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINTS
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');

        //SETTING THE PRIMARY KEYS
        $table->primary(['user_id', 'role_id']);
    });
```

permission table :

```
  Schema::create('permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and role table schema:

```
   Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of laravel policies here.

Create a policy for your Users.

Then create functions like canViewPosts, canAddPosts, canSeeViews, etc. and in each check if the the user has permission to do so.

Example UserPolicy

```
public function canView(User $user){
   return $user->permissions->canView; //given you have permissions relation on user
}
```

Then in your PostController you go like

```
$this->authorize('canView', User::class);
```

Check more in here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#introduction